# What is the benefit of using viewModel::onNextClick over {viewModel.onNextClick()}?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel

I understand that ::onNextClick point to the function inside the viewmodel to be executed but why is that beneficial. Is this just so that the function isn't called directly inside the Screen composable, if so why?

**The next button inside the screen composable**
[image: image1]

**The onNextClick function in the viewModel**
[image: image2]

Having trouble understanding as I know this seems to be common practice but the app runs fine either way and operates as expected.

I have tried looking at architecture guidelines and think it may be to do with seperation of concerns or something but genuinely can't find an explanation. Perhaps is just looks nicer haha? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is something that would help https://multithreaded.stitchfix.com/blog/2022/08/05/jetpack-compose-recomposition/

Comment: Yeh that article is quite good thank you. Feel like I could still benefit from a full answer as not sure how a new class creation is prevented as the article says. But it does definitely further cement that method reference is the way to go where possible.

Comment: I don't know Compose, so can't be 100% sure it doesn't implement some kind of optimizations for method references, but generally speaking, these 2 code fragments are almost the same and produce almost the same resulting bytecode. Some people just prefer one syntax over another.

Comment: Speaking about the above article, I would verify if what it says is true in practice. I don't say it isn't. But I believe at least this: "By using method references instead of a lambda, we will prevent the creation of a new class that references the view model." is clearly wrong. As said above, by using a method reference, we create almost the same bytecode, it also requires creating a new class and passing the view model to it. We can see this clearly in the resulting bytecode. So I would definitely verify other claims by this article.

Comment: there is an issue with compose 1.1.1 https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/280284177 just so if you are interested.